# Can I return an image from a url of a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, image, render

I am working with a reporting system that allows links to images (jpg, png) to be added to tables. I would like to dynamically create the images using javascript, probably in an html file. How can I set the output to be the image and *not* the html markup containing an image?

The reporting system only takes http/https as a scheme type. I tried hardcoding  data:image/png;base64,xxxx as the image url, and it won't work.

My other approach was this

```
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.height = canvas.width = 100;
            ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
 
            canvas.toBlob((blob) => {     
                console.log( 'size',blob.size, blob.type );
                document.write(blob);
                },'image/png');
            }
```

I thought by doing the write after the load the html would be replaced. Instead I got
the words [object blob]